# Why will timeuuid not have any collisions?

Tags: cassandra

I was reading [the Datastax CQL reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/uuid_type_r.html):

> Collisions that would potentially overwrite data that was not intended
> to be overwritten cannot occur.

Can someone explain to me why a collision will never occur?  Is it impossible or "highly" unlikely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cassandra's timeuuid is a [Version 1 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_.28date-time_and_MAC_address.29) which is based on the time and the MAC address of the machine generating the UUID.

The time used is accurate down to 100ns, so the chance of a collision is incredibly slim (a nano second is a millionth of a millisecond).

Comment: further yet, many implementations (including C*) use the 10,000 100ns resolution as a monotonically incrementing counter. This means that you have 10,000 calls to "new uuid" per ms per node. Highly unlikely to insert at a rate of 10,000 per ms, but if you do you can get collisions.

Comment: As Chris said there is an approach used to ensure uniqueness. https://github.com/marccarre/cassandra-utils/blob/d6a042f3b99add055d017fff95686ad0f4fbd802/src/main/java/com/carmatech/cassandra/TimeUUID.java#L83-L90 -- if this wasn't here then collisions would actually be pretty common. Even at ~5 per second there'd be ~8% chance every day that at least one collision occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra timeuuid is a Version 1 UUID(Type 1 UUID) which is based on:

1. A timestamp consisting of a count of 100-nanosecond intervals since
   15 October 1582 (the date of Gregorian reform to the Christian
   calendar).
2. A version (which should have a value of 1).
3. A variant(which should have a value of 2).
4. A sequence number, which can be a counter or a pseudo-random number.
5. A "node" which will be the machine's MAC address (which should make   the UUID unique across machines).

Using a pseudo-random number for the sequence number provides a 1 in a 16,384 chance that each UUID Class will have a unique id.

if you generate more than 10000 UUID per msec then they may collide.

1 msec = 10^6 ns

By this you can generate 10^6 UUID if we take ns level timestamp but 
as we take timestamp as 100ns count.

we will be have at most 10000 unique timestamps in one millisecond.

Now generating more than that on a single machine(which will have same MAC address), there is a chance to collide ass we also need to take sequence number into account.

If your application generates more than 10000 per ms, use another column to make a compound key which helps to avoid collisions.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, sort of. If you look into the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) you may see why. Even though it takes 10k per ms to have a 100% chance of a collision, to get a 50% collision you need much lower amount. Combined with the fact that this is happening *every millisecond* it doesn't take much to have a collision occur in a day.

Comment: However, none of that matter much since they have this approach to ensure no two timestamp generated are the same. If they are they increment by one. https://github.com/marccarre/cassandra-utils/blob/d6a042f3b99add055d017fff95686ad0f4fbd802/src/main/java/com/carmatech/cassandra/TimeUUID.java#L83-L90